# use photoswipe on dynamically created ul

Tags: jquery, photoswipe

I am working on a jquery mobile site which will have an image gallery populated by JSON/AJAX from instagram. I can get the images loaded just fine, but I want to take it one step further and use photoswipe to render the gallery. The issue that I am running into, is that if I add the call to photoswipe after the `ul` has been populated from the json feed, the `ul` has not actually been redrawn, so photoswipe can't find any child elements to use. Below is my script:

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="Photos">
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" data-icon="back" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>      
    <h1>Photos</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">   
    <div id="AdBanner">
    </div>
    <ul id="PhotoList">
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$("#Photos").live("pagebeforeshow", function(){
    $("ul#PhotoList").children().remove('li');
    var tag = MyTag
    $.getJSON("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" + tag + "/media/recent?callback=?&amp;client_id=####",
    function(data){
        $.each(data.data, function(i,item){
            $("ul#PhotoList").append('<li><a href="' + item.images.low_resolution.url + ' rel="external"><img src="' + item.images.low_resolution.url + '" alt="' + item.caption.text + '" width="200" /></a></li>');
        });
    });
    var photoSwipeInstance = $("ul#PhotoList a").photoSwipe();
});
```

Is there a way to refresh the `ul` prior to calling the photoswipe initiator, or is there another event that I should be using for photoswipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that this is not the "proper" answer to this question, but I did find a work-around to get the functionality that I wanted. Rather than using jquery ul.append to add the list items, I instead used a variable to add the list item to the variable, and then set the UL.innerhtml to the variable:

```
var Photos = "";
$.each(data.data, function(i,item){
    Photos += '<li><a href="' + item.images.low_resolution.url + '"><img src="' + item.images.low_resolution.url + '" alt="' + item.caption.text + '" width="80" /></a></li>';
});
document.getElementById('PhotoList').innerHTML = Photos;
```

Again, I am sure that this is not the correct way to do this, but it works for me, and in the absence of a better solution, it got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the images via JSON/AJAX *before* the page loads, or *after* it loads?

If before page load, did you take a look at the code for the examples that loads the images in JavaScript, and attaches that to the PhotoSwipe instance?

eg. http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/12-custom-target.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I am loading them after the page loads, so the example doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you try perhaps 'detaching' from your PhotoSwipe Instance, and then reattaching once you have the data?